# is it possible to run git specific command's in phpstorm's console

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to run git commands in phpStorm's console? For example, I want to run `git log`  command in the console that I open with `Tools->Terminal`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found an answer myself - just set the path to the git bash in the terminal path:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe"
```

[image]

Comment: It mostly works for me, except for git push, will not find the public keys

Comment: I'm not sure I've tested it with ssh, but I probably will, though I'm not sure it has anything to do with the terminal, more likely with ssh configuration that git uses.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe -login -i -v    //working on windows 10